# load 'rubyfile.rb" in irb vs. pry

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I created a completely empty ruby file `emptyrubyfile.rb`, saved it, and then opened my terminal app, dropped into `$ irb`, and loaded it `> load 'emptyrubyfile.rb'`. The output returned was => `> true`, which seems, to me, to be the expected output.

I then exited irb, `> exit`, and dropped into pry `$ pry`. I loaded the same empty file `> load 'emptyrubyfile.rb'`, but the output returned was => `*`. To escape the `*` I can use either `exit` or `quit`.

I realize that irb and pry, are similar, but different. My question is: what is the difference and why does the pry output expect more input from me and what is it asking me for at the `*` prompt?

Comment: `irb` and `pry` have the same behavior for me in this case. Are you sure you typed the `load` command correctly in `pry`? `pry` prints `*` when it's waiting for you to finish a string. Make sure you got the closing `'`.

Answer (score 2):

You would have missed the ending `'` while loading it in pry. There is no difference between irb and pry on this aspect. I'm guessing you typed

```
> load 'emptyrubyfile.rb
```

Comment: Close, I incorrectly typed `> load 'emptyrubyfile.rb"`. I promise to be more attentive before posting next time. thank you.

Comment: I knew the title was a clue..

Comment: Oh, yes. It was in the title all the time. Blind me.